# Why does typescript complain that an object must be an object in spread types

Tags: typescript, object, merge, spread-syntax

Why does TSC say that "...base" must be an object, how do I resolve this problem while still retaining the types from the "base" object.

```
function aFunction<T extends object>(base: T) {
  const anObject = { test:"value" }
  if (typeof base !== 'object') { return }

// the following line causes a TSC error, saying that spread types can only be
// created from object types and highlighting base as the problem...  wut?

  const merged = { ...base, anObject }
  return merged
}
```

For example, the following does not have a compiler error however loses all type information of 'base'.

```
function aFunction(base: object) {
  const anObject = { test:value }
  if (typeof base !== 'object') { return }

  const merged = { ...base, anObject }
  return merged
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<T extends object>(base: T)` means `base` is of a generic type `T`.

And the type system of TypeScript does not understand generic types yet.
([#10727](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727))

Workarounds:

1. Refactor your code to not use `...`
2. Wait for [#10727](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727) to be resolved.
3. Change to other type checkers, for example, flow:

Flow reports no errors on your code:

```
/* @flow */

function aFunction<T: Object>(base: T) {
  const anObject = { test:"value" }
  if (typeof base !== 'object') { return }

  const merged = { ...base, anObject }
  return merged
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, is there a recommended way of merging objects in typescript that preserves the type information?  I've refactored to assert the objects, which works, just feels rather hacky.

const merged = <typeof base & typeof anObject>{...<any>base, anObject}

Comment: @laramie I do not know how. I would use `Object.assign` as a workaround instead.

Answer (score 2):

Spread and rest are not yet supported on generics at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet base is of `type T` which inherits from object. Well you know in javascript its not a strong relationship hence not an `is a` relationship so T is not necessarily an `object`. T just prototypically inherits from object.Also typescript has no understanding for generics.So no support for spread.

In code snippet 2 `base` is of type object and yet typescript has support for object spread and distructuring .values of type object can be spread.this feature is used mainly to make copys of objects.So this is why it gives no errors.

Comment: This is just a weakness of TypeScript as #10727.